# MobileAds: Add Permission INTERNET

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, google-mobile-ads

While trying to make `MobileAds` work in an Android app of mine I have the following issue:

Although the *AndroidManifest.xml* file contains this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I get the following problem in Android Studio:

[image]

And if I choose to click "Add Permission INTERNET", a copy of the same line is inserted in *AndroidManifest.xml* but the problem stays the same.

For information *adView* is of type *AdView*.

Can someone guess what I am missing and give me a hint on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project, and then invalidate caches and restart?

Comment: I have done "Clean Project" followed by "Rebuild Project" but it does not have much effect that I can see.

Comment: I can read in the list of problems in Android Studio:
"Missing permissions required by BaseAdView.loadAd: android.permission.INTERNET"

Comment: I also did "Invalidate Caches" and restarted; the problem is still there.

Comment: Hello use <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: I tried and it works at least partially. But when I later use "adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())" I get similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

if you have provided the required internet permission and the problem is still exist then in the adview.setAdlistener

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {}
```

Change

```
@Override
public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {}
```

to

```
@Override
public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadError) {}
```